hive use in flutter offline and online condition
when the internet is connect data get dynamic but when the internet is offline data gets to hive local database how to use it is briefly explained in Flutter. I implemented hive and tried to fetch data from the hive display but I still fetching errors some time so I need to give a proper example and it's used.

Share you code snippet which is causing error. Please follow https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/ if you want to know how to set up hive properly. For samples refer https://github.com/hivedb/samples
